# Sort Array of Objects by Date

Tags: jquery, arrays, linq, sorting

I am using [jLinq](http://hugoware.net/projects/jlinq/demo) to query an `Array` of `Objects`
this is my `Array` of `Objects`:

```
wo:
 [{ ID: 1, 'CreatedYM': '2015-Jun'},
  { ID: 2, 'CreatedYM': '2014-May'}, 
  { ID: 3, 'CreatedYM': '2015-Jan'}, 
  { ID: 4, 'CreatedYM': '2015-Aug'}, 
  { ID: 5, 'CreatedYM': '2014-Dec'}]
```

this is my query:

```
jlinq.from( wo ).group( "CreatedYM" );
```

I want it returns my array sorted By CreatedYM, like this:

```
 [{ ID: 2, 'CreatedYM': '2014-May'},
  { ID: 5, 'CreatedYM': '2014-Dec'}, 
  { ID: 3, 'CreatedYM': '2015-Jan'},
  { ID: 1, 'CreatedYM': '2015-Jun'}, 
  { ID: 4, 'CreatedYM': '2015-Aug'},]
```

is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort the array using [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function

```
var arr =  [{ ID: 1, 'CreatedYM': '2015-Jun'},
  { ID: 2, 'CreatedYM': '2014-May'}, 
  { ID: 3, 'CreatedYM': '2015-Jan'}, 
  { ID: 4, 'CreatedYM': '2015-Aug'}, 
  { ID: 5, 'CreatedYM': '2014-Dec'}
];
var sortedarr = arr.sort(function(a,b){   
    // convert them into dates
    var d1 = new Date(Date.parse(a.CreatedYM));
    var d2 = new Date(Date.parse(b.CreatedYM));
    return d1 > d2 ? 1  // if d1 > d2 return 1
    : d1 < d2 ? -1 // if d1 < d2 return -1
    : 0; // else return 0
});
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/cmozfej1/)

Or an even shorter version

```
var sortedarr = arr.sort(function(a,b){    
    return new Date(Date.parse(a.CreatedYM)) - new Date(Date.parse(b.CreatedYM));   
});
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/09dgn0ht/)

Answer (score 1):

'2014-May' is probably not a valid date time...(i.e. can't sort)
First populate the array with valid date time e.g. '2014/05/01' then you can sort it and finally project (select) the format as YYYY-MM...jlinq.from(wo).sort("CreatedYM").group( "CreatedYM" ) by their documentation